# creating pdf from web page with SWF files

Tags: php, .net, html, pdf, flash

I am trying to generate a pdf from a web page which has pictures and swf files.

Final pdf should have pictures (swf should be converted into image, last frame is sufficient).

I am able to generate pdf when only images are there but i am stuck in creating pdf when the web page has swf files.

Comment: Are you trying to do this operationally (you are sitting there looking a the web page you want to turn into a PDF) or are you wanting this to be "programmatically", you put a button on a page and when a user clicks it a PDF is output?

Comment: Thanks, i want this to be programmatic, user clicks on a button and PDF is the output.

Comment: Doesn't Adobe acrobat give any api to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) before to render pdfs programatically from web sites. I'm not sure if it'll cope with swf but it may do since it uses a version of webkit compiled in to qt.

Comment: I tried this, it is not working with the swf. In the pdf it is just drawing a placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `wkhtmltopdf --enable-plugins`. But according to this bugreport it might not work http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=48 with the flash plugin (Java however does!).

Another option is running a browser in headless mode, or on a virtual X. Firefox3 works supposedly if you use the [extension "CommandLinePrint"](http://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2).

```
Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1600x1200x24 &
firefox --display=localhost:2.0 -print http://flashgames.com -printmode pdf -printfile '/tmp/test.pdf'
```

Infos stolen from http://spielwiese.la-evento.com/xelasblog/archives/31-Headless-Firefox-als-HTML-to-PDF.html (in German however).

But there are a few more guides like this ("headless browser, HTML to PDF"). I would totally link to one of the dupes here on Stackoverflow. But I'm too lazy to search right now.

Comment: Just FYI, the search string "headless browser, HTML to PDF" comes up with 7 results, and they are all this page. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to output the target page as a PDF I would look at using .rdlc [(Report Definition Language Client)](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/). It is part of the Microsoft.Reporting namespace and is designed to work with asp.net. It is freely usable and redistributable. 
In many cases the layout of a web page is not "printer friendly". By using this technique you can re-arrange the layout and spacing of the PDF output to a presentation that is more printer friendly.

This will not "directly" convert your page to a PDF, but rather allow you to adapt your page layout and data to a dataset and use that to build a report. That report can then be output programmatically at runtime using the reportviewer control. If this approach interests you, let me know and I will be glad to provide more help getting you through setting it up and using.