# generate images from swf

Tags: php, python, perl

Is there any library/module available with which i can generate images from a swf file?

The problem i am trying to solve is: I want to create a pdf from a web page and i am having problems in doing that when the web page has swf [(question in stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759299/creating-pdf-from-web-page-with-swf-files) 
I am thinking if i am able to read a swf and write out an image, i will be able to solve the above the problem

Will appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Not simply. None of the open source flash players (swfdec, gnash) yet works reliably, AFAIK. That leaves only the proprietary flash plugin, which isn't designed to be called from a script. You probably have to script a web browser, or at least a rendering engine that can handle the plugin (webkit/gecko).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, that is quite a hard task. I've spent hours looking for a program that could fulfill such a task. However, I eventually only found one. It isn't open-source but would really help you I guess.

[Flash Animation Source](http://www.medialooks.com/products/directshow_filters/flash_source.html) can output all frames of a SWF file. It uses a DirectShow filter to do so. Therefore, a Windows operating system is required should you not want to use WINE.

In short, you'll just need to install Flash Animation Source on your computer and then find a way to get DirectShow frames using your desired programming language. Everything else is actually quite easy. You tell Windows the directory and the name of your SWF file and it'll do the rest, thus delivering you with an image. And did you know DirectShow filters can deliver all frames of a video? Therefore, you can choose which one you'd like to have.

By the way, please don't try to find another way to get an image of your SWF file. Believe me, you won't find one. I have looked for an open-source program that fits my needs but all of them fail. You need to use the propriertary Adobe Flash player for your outputs. There is no other option as the open-source alternatives still need a lot of development to genuinely output the vector-based frame as it is.

Comment: Wow it is working. Thank you Fabianius, I am able to open normal swf files in the sample applications included in the package. I am stuck in reading the swf files that get arguments through flashvars, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Have a look at the IdlFile you find enclosed with the program. It shows you how to set the width and height of your SWF file and other options. In your case, use `HRESULT SetVariable([in] BSTR bstrName, [in] BSTR bstrValue);` to set flash variables.